# Версия Bootstrap между 2.3.2 и 3.0?

Tags: bootstrap

Где взять такой Bootstrap?
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Официально вышла третья версия в FLAT/METRO стиле (тотальный минимализм), однако в этом примере того минимализма нету. Хотел просто рипнуть пример, чтобы не отвлекать вас, да там в CSS всё сжали в одну строку.

Comment: ничего не понял, что вам надо именно ? less файлы дефолтные для bootstrsap 3.1.1  ?

Comment: Нет, мне нужен Bootstrap 3, только не настолько простым (мне нужен такой как на официальном примере по ссылке выше)

Answer (score 1):

Там базовая тема и разметка, вот исходник: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.1.1/docs/examples/theme

Вот исходник темы https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.1.1/less

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap-3.ru документация на русском